# converting ios 6 app to ios 7

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

This might seem to you as an odd question but still I am facing lot of problems. 
I have an app which is developed in ios6 and now I have to migrate it to ios7.
There are several problems : 
All Views of the app are shifted upwards and there is space left at bottom of the app. The space left is equal to the status bar.
There is an error of table view WrraperClass.

Help me out.

Comment: @AlexWien - point taken, comment deleted.  It's been a long day & I should save my impatience for the truly bad questions - it's not like there's a dearth of them.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Probably you are using one of it : `UINavigatopnBar OR UITabBarController` :

> If so then try with the translucency  & uncheck these (under top bars
>   & under bottom bars ) in the inspector

[image]

Comment: @AlexWien Hmmm... .......

Comment: What if I am using the old style .xib file instead of storyboard these options are not displaying

Comment: Yes how can I deal with XIB ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
In my app I position most UI elements programaticaly:

In ios7 views always the property `wantsFullScreen` is true, where in ios6 it is false by default. So in ios7 postion 0 is at the top of the status Bar, where in ios6 it is below the status bar.
Just add an constant - the height of the status bar - to all y coordinates.

For UI elements positioned in XIB via UI Builder try the answer of Kumar KI