# scrollView incorrect position xcode 5

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xcode5

I don't know why I always get stuck with scrollview's position issue... I just want to display scrollview after a label at 5 px distance, but its taking extra margin on top. I am using storyboard - xcode 5. Scrollview positions correctly when I test with iOS 7, but creates problem in iOS 6 simulator.

**Note:** I am not using any constraints.

**In storyboard,**

[image]

**iOS 6 snapshot**

[image]

**iOS 7 snapshot**

[image]

**Simple piece of code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets)])
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

  //add subviews to scrollview

    _latestNewsLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    _latestNewsLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;

    _latestNewsScroll.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    _latestNewsScroll.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _categoriesList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"US World", @"World", @"Business", @"Political", @"Entertainment", @"Sports", @"IT", nil];
    selectedIndex = -1;

    [_collectionView registerClass:[CustomCollectionCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Category"];
    CollectionViewLayout *collLayout = [[CollectionViewLayout alloc] init];
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:collLayout];    

}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    CGRect newFrame = _latestNewsScroll.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y = _latestNewsLabel.frame.origin.y + _latestNewsLabel.frame.size.height + 5;
    _latestNewsScroll.frame = newFrame;    

    newFrame = _collectionView.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y = _latestNewsScroll.frame.origin.y + _latestNewsScroll.frame.size.height + 10;
    _collectionView.frame = newFrame;

}
```

Comment: Check this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159621/converting-ios-6-app-to-ios-7/19159882#19159882**

Comment: I have already unchecked both topbar and bottom bar