# UIWebView built-in audio player navigation bar has wrong size on iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

In my app I have an `UIWebView`, and when I press on an audio link, the quick time audio player is opening, and is streaming that audio file. Everything works fine, but I met a problem on **iOS6**, player is placed below status bar (navigation bar is missing), and I'm not able to press **Done** button. See the attached images:

**Normal State:**
[image: Normal State:]

**What I have in my case:**
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Check this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159621/converting-ios-6-app-to-ios-7/19159882#19159882**

Comment: @KumarKl it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the source of the problem.

I have an `UINavigationBar` category, where I'm setting a custom bar height for some cases. This is my old category code, where problem persists:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (customHeight)

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
    CGFloat customNavBarHeight = 70.0;
    CGSize newSize = self.frame.size;
    if (self.tag == navBarTagThatMustHaveCustomHeight)
    {
        newSize.height = customNavBarHeight;
    }
    return newSize;
}
@end
```

And in case when quick time player was presenting, this method returned (0,0) size, and that's why its navigation bar had such strange appearance. So I fixed the issue by changing `sizeThatFits` method this way:

```
#define navigationBarPortraitDefaultHeight 44
@implementation UINavigationBar (customHeightBar)

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
    CGFloat customNavBarHeight = 70.0;
    CGFloat navHeight = self.frame.size.height == 0.0f ? navigationBarPortraitDefaultHeight : self.frame.size.height;
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.superview.bounds.size.width, navHeight);
    if (self.tag == navBarTagThatMustHaveCustomHeight)
    {
        newSize.height = customNavBarHeight;
    }
    return newSize;
}

@end
```

Hope this will help someone with the same silly issue.