# How to make an app for iOS 6 compatible which is built in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My application is in iOS7 compatible, Xcode 5. Now, I have to make it iOS 6 compatible, so when I set deployment target iOS 6.1, all frame changes, what is solution for this? 
I have attached screenshot for reference. 
[image: first one for iOS 7]

[image: second one for iOS 6]

[image: Attached screenshot of storyboard]

One thing to notice, I have used `storyboard` and have `not used autoLayout`.

Comment: For ios6 in the xib file use delta to change the layout

Comment: Did you verify the auto layout for views?

Comment: Will solve few of your problems.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159621/converting-ios-6-app-to-ios-7/19159882#19159882

Comment: @karan One thing to notice, I have used storyboard and have not used auto layout.

Comment: @KumarKl , I have implemented tab bar programmatically .

Comment: i think auto layout property is not depends on using xib or storyboard . have you implemented autoresizing mask values for views?

Comment: @karan , Yes Even when I try, it looks ok in storyboard but in device it is same.

Comment: can you post your storyboard?

Comment: @karan , I have attached storyboard screenshot.

Comment: setting proper autoresize for every subview will help you to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

First of all of you should understand new iOS 7 UI. Check it here: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html)

There are few differences in UI that are connected to status bar new visualization and etc.

I have noticed that some elements have different y offset positions for iOS 6 and iOS 7.

So if you use storyboard or xib you can find

So if you can find **iOS 6/7 Deltas** option. I've attache screenshot for you:

[image]

Just modify delta Y position for all of view using -20 value because of status bar issue.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: nothing at all working. setting -20 could not resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Select each ViewController in your Storyboard and, tick both options "Under top bars" , "Under bottm bars"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look Size Inspector at 4th position in the utilities area at right side and change value of delta Y in IOS 6/7 to -20 and delta Height to 20.  I hope it will work

[image]

Comment: change the value of dalta Height to 20

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically you'd set your view controller's `wantsFullScreenLayout` to `YES`. It defaults to `NO` under iOS 6 but both defaults to `YES` and is deprecated as of 7. Or set the "Use Full Screen (Deprecated)" tick box in the interface builder.